# How can I run different scripts based on time?

Tags: javascript, time

I'm basic in java-scripts and HTML, So I want to ask: How can I run different scripts based on the time?,
like: from 6AM -to- 7PM, do `<script>..</script>` else do another script.

---

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: By checking the current date time and execute the script? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm basic just answer me with correct code please : )

Comment: You need to show what you have already tried.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: Ziad, ofcourse you're young in javascript, climb the stairs step by step, if you know the basics this question is not a big issue at all, people dont write free code on SO. So just, try something come back with few issues you have faced, people will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var hour = new Date().getHours(); // hour will get current hour like 0 to 23
    switch(hour) {
      case '6': // code in this case will run if current time is in 6am to 7am
        alert('hi, it's in 6 a.m to 7 a.m now');
        break;
      case '7': // any other hour
        // add your code you want to run between 7 - 8 am
        break;
    }`

Comment: Thank you very very much : )

Comment: If your want a period cross hours like '2am - 6am', you can stack up `case '2'` to `case '5'`. But in this situation, **if(){} else {}** works better.

Comment: By the way, use a more handy 'IDE'. I like **atom** and **VisualStudio Code**, free and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Date().toLocaleString()`, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+(?=\:)/`, `.split()` with `RegExp` `/.*\s/`

```
var now = new Date().toLocaleString().split(/,/)[1].trim();

var curr = now.match(/\d+(?=\:)/), ampm = now.split(/.*\s/)[1];

if ((curr >= 6 && ampm === "AM") || (curr < 7 && ampm === "PM")) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to use location.href instead of href if you want the page to jump to the desired location.  You would also have to have the code executed after the page is processed so that the anchors are already defined.  This can be done by either putting the script at the end of the body or using window.onload or document.onload to set of method as being executed after the features of the page are loaded.  In the following case, the jump is triggered by a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Using hour of day in Javascript</title>
<script>
function processDate() {
   var outField = document.getElementById("out");
   var date = new Date();
   var time = date.getHours();
   alert("Hour is " + time);
   outField.value = time;
   location.href="#5";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>See:</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp"
    target="_blank">http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp"
    target="_blank">
    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</a></li>
</ul>
<form>
<p><input type="button" onclick="processDate()" value="Show Date"></input></p>
<p><input type="text" id="out" size="50"></input></p>
</form>
<p><a name="5">This is point 5</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is helpful